# In a .netcore app, why can't i replace a dll with an earlier (older) version without getting a runtime error

Tags: .net, vb.net

Let's say i have a small solution with 1 exe and 1 dll. They are not signed. With the .netframework, i use to be able make a fix in the exe and replace just the exe in a deployed app. Now, with .net core (.net7) the application complains saying it's looking for a new version of the dll. That is assuming the new exe and dll version are bumped.

the dll is just a regular dll that's referenced from the exe. it's not being dynamically loaded or anything.

Since when does the .net loader (or whatever it's called) care about what version a dll is if nothing is signed, all files are in the same directory (not loading from gac). It's like it's now forcing a dependent dll version to be greater than or equal to the version the exe was built with (and is referenced in the app manifest of the exe i guess).

what am i missing?

Comment: it is a fact of Dot net , you need to specify the version when you compile it, so you must live with it

Comment: I'm not talking about nuget packages. in this case, i'm referring to a project reference ...

Comment: i am also nit talking about nuget. You have a dll with vrtsion1.3 and you compile your program. If you now add version 2.1 the program will not start, you have to add the new dll to the program see if everything is running and compile new

Comment: if the dll version is new than the one the app was originally compiled with, it still work with .net core. Also, according to the documentation i can find, it says that the default probing algorithm is to load the dll by name, I've spent 15 years building .net framework apps and have many times built a new .exe with a new version and had no problem dropping into an existing/deployed instance of that app that still used all the previous dlls. i'm so confused....

Comment: Do you have automatic Version numbers enabled? Is the DLL in the same solution as the exe?  When you build a new exe is the dll version being incremented? If so, then at runtime the exe will attempt to load a version of the dll at least as high as the one it was compiled against.

Comment: How are you referencing the dll?  How is the dll versioned (in particular, the assembly version)?  If there is a version number included in the reference (and it isn't identified as not version-specific) then the assembly resolution will insist on exactly matching the referenced version.

Comment: It should work quite the same with .NET core/5+ as it used to with .NET Framework in that context (no strong name, no gac). Do you any reproducing project?

Answer (score 0):

I have some ideas you might look at.

Depending on how old your code is, you might look at your .csproj files to see what sort of mapping they are doing with your .dlls. Something that most people don't know is that VS doesn't do much in the way of updating the formats id .sln and .csproj files. Some of the older formats had a lot of data in them defining dependent file versions, along with mapping forwarding. (Ex: V3.0 - V5.2 -> V5.2) It use to make updating nuget package versions way more interesting than it should have been.

I tried to find an example of this, but it looks like all my projects go upgraded. Take a look inside the project files and see if and how your .dll is being referenced, there might be something in there that is getting built into the .exe. I have found that more modern .csproj file formats are much simpler and more forgiving and I make sure to rebuild project files using the latest formats whenever I can. This will often fix strange versioning problems you see in VS.

The other thought I had was, check the versions of the .dll to make sure that you aren't trying to plug in a .net core app into a later version that doesn't support it. The .net ecosystem has changed a lot over the years, from the .net framework, to .net core and standard. Even if the code you write hasn't changed  by a single character, compiling it as a .net framework .dll will likely make it incompatible with .net core exes. While the logic might be the same, the interface will be different.

Hope that helps!